# How do I add code to my Web Browser in PyQt5 to make changes to the internet?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I’m using PyQt5 for a browser in python and I want to know how I can write code that makes changes to the internet (the web) in PyQt5. I want to be able to connect to the web and for example change where a website goes to. If someone searches google.com in their url bar I want the internet to go to my website.com.

My code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class MyWebBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(MyWebBrowser, self).__init__()

        self.window=QWidget()
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Brave")

        self.layout=QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal = QHBoxLayout()

        self.url_bar = QTextEdit()
        self.url_bar.setMaximumHeight(30)

        self.go_btn=QPushButton("Go")
        self.go_btn.setMinimumHeight(30)

        self.back_btn = QPushButton("<")
        self.back_btn.setMinimumHeight(30)

        self.forward_btn = QPushButton(">")
        self.forward_btn.setMinimumHeight(30)

        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.url_bar)
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.go_btn)
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.back_btn)
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.forward_btn)

        self.browser=QWebEngineView()

        self.go_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate(self.url_bar.toPlainText()))
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.browser.back)
        self.forward_btn.clicked.connect(self.browser.forward)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.window.show()

    def navigate(self,url):
        if not url.startswith("http"):
            url = "http://" + url
            self.url_bar.setText(url)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
app=QApplication([])
window=MyWebBrowser()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: "Make changes to the internet"?!?

Comment: @musicamante Like if I go to google.com I want the website to go to my website.com

Comment: 1. you already have a function that tells the browser which url to go based on the `url` argument: check that `url` object and change it according to your needs; 2. with all due respect, if you want to learn programming, you have to be more careful about terminology: the phrase "make changes to the internet" makes absolutely no sense, especially considering what you're asking.

Comment: Ok but I want the change to occur on the internet also @musicamante

Comment: As said, "change on the internet" makes no sense at all. Try to explain yourself better.

Comment: @musicamante when people visit google.com in their browser I want the changes I made in my code to affect them too. When someone at their house  visits google.com I want their browser to also visit my website

Comment: @GaryDamonSchlitt: That's obviously impossible.  How would anything work if anyone could just change where any URL takes you to?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment doesn't really clarify anything; it actually makes it even more confusing. I suggest you to take your time and rephrase your request in order to make clear what you want to do, using *proper technical terms*. If you have difficulties with the English language, please try to find somebody that could help you with it. If spoken/written language is not the issue, then I strongly urge you to do more research on the topics related to your requests, as you cannot ask about technical subjects if you don't even understand how to properly use terminology.

Comment: See: [QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) and  [QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `navigate` function is what gets called when the Go button in the browser is clicked. You can make the `navigate` function modify the URL when the URL contains the string `google.com`:

```
def navigate(self, url):
    if not url.startswith("http"):
        url = "http://" + url
        self.url_bar.setText(url)

    # redirect to your website
    if "google.com" in url:
        url = "http://stackoverflow.com"

    self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
```

This way, when you try to visit `google.com`, the address bar will still say `http://google.com`, but the browser will actually be sent to `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: This may work in *very* simple cases, but there are lots of good reasons if browser devs spend awful lots of time to write/fix address bar code. For instance, what if `google.com` is actually part of the url (ie: a complex urls such as `google.community.website.com`, or even a basic query as in `website.com/search?q=google.com`)? I really appreciate your efforts, but, with all due respect, the OP question was poorly written in its description, concept and terminology, and we, as "answerers", shouldn't promote such behavior by providing answers, especially if they're vague and/or imprecise.

Comment: Besides which, this answer doesn't "change the internet"!  :-)

Comment: @BrenBarn Interestingly enough, it's actually "the internet" that changes the results of this answer ;-)